# python-django not able to create dir and file

Tags: python, django

This code snippet gives me error , i don't have idea why it's throwing error because i am opening file **'+w'** so if file not present there then python will create.

response is file path and default_storage from Django

anyone have idea why it is not working

```
with default_storage.open(response, 'w+') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
    writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])
    log.info(writer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what `default_storage` is in this case, I am going to assume you just want to write to a file. If you want to preserve the contents of the file, if it exists, then yo should use `'a'` for appending. If you don't care about the contents and are OK with overwriting, then you can use `'w'`.

```py
with open(response, 'a') as csv_file:
    pass #do stuff
```

Use separate `with open` blocks for reading and writing.

Comment: can I stop overwriting?

Comment: @KiranChauhan, you can use `'a'` like I said.